# VisualGDB: Define timestamp in GCC linker arguments

Tags: gcc, linker, timestamp

I'm trying to link with an external symbol which should hold a timestamp. I'm entering it into the LDFLAGS line in the VisualGSB properties dialogue.

I tried to do a

```
gcc -Wl,-gc-sections,--defsym,TIMESTAMP='date +%s' test.c
```

But the linker says:

> error: +%s`: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *output* of the `date` executable, you need backticks or `$(...)`:

```
gcc -Wl,-gc-sections,--defsym,TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s) test.c
```

Using single quotes, as you have done, will simply give you the *literal* string `date +%s`, which is obviously causing issues for the tool-chain.

You can see this in the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'date +%s'
date +%s

pax> echo `date +%s`
1465979960

pax> echo $(date +%s)
1465979967
```

Note that this is from the `bash` shell. If your commands are embedded somewhere else, you'll likely need to find another method suited to that.

For example, within a `makefile`, you would need to escape the `$`:

```
gcc -Wl,-gc-sections,--defsym,TIMESTAMP=$$(date +%s) test.c
```

Comment: That gives me a "error: +%s): No such file or directory"

Comment: @Christoph, are you running that `gcc` command from a `bash` shell or somewhere else? If you're not using `bash`, it won't work. I'd also suggest trying the commands in my transcript to see if they have a similar issue?

Comment: It's run as part of the VisualGDB config dialogue... It instantly checks the toolchain consistence

Comment: @Christoph: you're going to have to find out how (or even if) VisualGDB allows you to substitute the output of external commands into your settings? I'd try it with the `$$` since it's somewhat likely it would be using `make` under the covers but, if not, you'll need further investigation of the tool to see whether it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

In a shell you can't embed commands in other commands just like that, instead you need to tell the shell about the commands using special characters: The backtick (backward single quote).

```
gcc -Wl,-gc-sections,--defsym,TIMESTAMP="`date +%s`" test.c
```

Using backticks like shown above should be compatible between just about all shells.

Comment: now i get "undefined symbol `date' referenced in expression"

Comment: @Christoph Are you using double-quote around the command expansion, or continue with single quotes? Either use no quotes at all or use double-quotes (as in my answer).

Comment: I did copy and paste. So double-quotes and backward single quotes inside

Comment: @Christoph Please update your question with the shell you are using. With a simple test program and using Bash, the command as I shown should work fine.